# Posting form-data AND a file to ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have this ASP.NET Web API method, and I want to post an object and in the same time, a file!

```
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post(Facility facility)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest();

        // Check if the request contains multipart/form-data.
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        string root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data");
        var provider = new MultipartFormDataStreamProvider(root);

            // Read the form data.
            await Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);

            // This illustrates how to get the file names.
            foreach (MultipartFileData file in provider.FileData)
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(file.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName);
                Trace.WriteLine("Server file path: " + file.LocalFileName);
            }
            // Logic
            // Login

        return Ok(facilityManager.Insert(facility));
    }
```

And I want to call it, so I send this http request with fiddler:

Header:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=-------------------------acebdf13572468
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: localhost:44301
Content-Length: 3279
```

Body:

```
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fieldNameHere"; filename="credits.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

<@INCLUDE *C:\Program Files (x86)\Fiddler2\credits.txt*@>
---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="facility"
Content-Type: application/json
{
    "FacilityTypeId":"1"
}
---------------------------acebdf13572468--
```

I get an 415 error code with response text:

> {"message":"The request entity's media type 'multipart/form-data' is not supported for this resource.","exceptionMessage":"No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'Facility' from content with media type 'multipart/form-data'.","exceptionType":"System.Net.Http.UnsupportedMediaTypeException","stackTrace":" at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync[T](HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions.ReadAsAsync(HttpContent content, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding.ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Type type, IEnumerable`1 formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"}

I searched a lot before asking but couldn't find any solution. Thnaks for helping.

**EDIT:**

A note: If I remove the "facility" parameter, and let the method only for uploading the file, it works perfect, but I want to post JSON and a file together.

Comment: Hello, do you have solution to this problem? I am having the same problem.

Comment: @uikrosoft, Don't set arguments (parameters) in the api function (Make it without parameters). And get your parameters values inside that function from the post body. That worked for me.

Comment: Here is a complete tutorial: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data,-part-2

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. Solved by [MultipartDataMediaFormatter](https://github.com/iLexDev/ASP.NET-WebApi-MultipartDataMediaFormatter) for ASP.NET WebApi. How to use:

1. Find and install from Nuget packages **MultipartDataMediaFormatter**.
2. Add current formatter to WebApi formatters collection:

   - if WebApi hosted on IIS (on Application Start). :

     - `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.Add(new FormMultipartEncodedMediaTypeFormatter());`
   - if WebApi is self-hosted:

     - `new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(<url>).Formatters.Add(new FormMultipartEncodedMediaTypeFormatter());`

After that you can post objec with file together in one model.

*Note*: In Nuget packages version 1.1.0 is not the last. They are not updated yet. Maybe possible to install latest version manually.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Answer (score 3):

"mulitpart/form-data" so we register the UploadMultipartMediaTypeFormatter

```
public class UploadMultipartMediaTypeFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter
{
    UploadMultipartMediaTypeFormatter()
    {
        SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("multipart/form-data"));
    }
}
```

* register in global.asax or (see sandbox code)

```
config.Formatters.Add(new UploadMultipartMediaTypeFormatter());
```

The WebApi will now call MediaTypeFormatter.ReadFromStreamAsync and we can call the HttpContent.ReadAsMultipartAsync extension from there.

Comment: But in this way, I couldn't get the uploaded file, the post is not multi-part anymore! Am I saying right?

Comment: you are right. could you please check this article. i have edited my answer

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work, but I forced to implement CanReadType and CanWriteType methods and I returned true. When I call the api, I get response 500 and no content! :(